# Put commas in PHP number variable

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I am using a script in my header.php to display how many users are registered (for example it says 79447 PLAYERS), but I want it to say 79,447 players instead. How would I go about adding commas? I've tried a few methods but failed.

```
<?php
include('session.php');
?>

<style>
.navbar {
    font-family: 'Numans', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.navbar-inverse {
    background: #00aa00;
}
.dropdown-menu li a:hover, .dropdown-menu-default li a:hover {
    color: #00aa00;
}
.dropdown-menu {
min-width: 100%;
border-radius: 0px;
}
.navbar .navbar-form .form-control-wrapper .form-control, .navbar .navbar-form .form-control {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.nav>li>a>img {
    max-width: 20px;
    margin-right: 4px;
}
</style>

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-inverse-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://epicmc.us">EPICMC</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-inverse-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="https://epicmc.us/">HOME</a></li>
            <?php $remote_api = file_get_contents('http://epicmc.us/api.php?task=total'); $remote_job = json_decode($remote_api); echo '<li>'; echo '<a href="javascript:void(0)">'; echo substr($remote_job->amount,0,75); ?> PLAYERS</li></a>
            <li class="dropdown">
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" action ="stats.php" method="GET"><input type="text" name="player" class="form-control col-lg-8" autocomplete="off" placeholder="USERNAME"></form>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <img src="https://minepic.org/avatar/20/<?php echo strtoupper($_SESSION['login_user']); ?>">
                <?php if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
                echo "HOWDY, ";
                echo strtoupper($_SESSION['login_user']);
                } else {
                Echo "HOWDY, GUEST";
                }?><b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <?php if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
                echo '<li><a href="https://epicmc.us/login.php">ACCOUNT</a></li>';
                echo '<li><a href="#">NOTIFICATIONS <span class="badge">0</span></a></li>';
                echo '<li><a href="https://epicmc.us/logout.php">LOGOUT</a></li>';
                } else {
                echo '<li><a href="https://epicmc.us/login.php">LOGIN</a></li>';
                }?>
              </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code snippet it looks like the number of users is in the variable `$remote_job->amount`

```
echo number_format($remote_job->amount);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php